# Angular 6 - Expression has changed after it was checked, build modes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting below error in some components when build is done for debug mode, which is **ng build**.
But as soon as I change build mode to prod using **ng build --prod**, these errors goes away.

I am unclear why this is happening.

**Error:**
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Thanks

Comment: could you provide a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: Check your `environments:dev` object values is correct  in `angular-cli.js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this error does not appear in `prod` mode but appears on `dev` build. That is the `warning/error` which says that your input variables are modified before the change detection has completed.

In Dev mode, change detection triggers two times for every `@Input` change, so if any of the variable being updated in child components change in between, then you will get this error.

In prod mode, change detection triggers only once, so it wont recognize that input was changed during change detection.

Read more about this error [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) and how you can avoid it.